# How do you prevent overwrites in arrays java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to stop elements in sourceArray from being overwritten. Currently, the code works until I reach a point where `i` changes, at that point overwrites begin.

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_accounts; ++i) {
    ...
    for (int j = 1; j < elm.length; ++j) {

        int src = Integer.parseInt(elm[j]);
        System.out.println("DEBUG");
        System.out.println("Value of i: "+i);
        System.out.println("Value of j:"+j);
        System.out.println("Value of elm[j]"+ elm[j]);
        System.out.println("Value of sourceArray index"+(i+j));
        sourceArray[(i+j-1)] = src;
    }
```

Snippet of debug information to demonstrate issue:

```
DEBUG
Value of i: 0
Value of j:1
Value of elm[j]22
Value of sourceArray index1
DEBUG
Value of i: 0
Value of j:2
Value of elm[j]36
Value of sourceArray index2
DEBUG
Value of i: 0
Value of j:3
Value of elm[j]39
Value of sourceArray index3
DEBUG
Value of i: 0
Value of j:4
Value of elm[j]45
Value of sourceArray index4
DEBUG
Value of i: 0
Value of j:5
Value of elm[j]56
Value of sourceArray index5
DEBUG
Value of i: 0
Value of j:6
Value of elm[j]81
Value of sourceArray index6
DEBUG
Value of i: 0
Value of j:7
Value of elm[j]89
Value of sourceArray index7
DEBUG
Value of i: 0
Value of j:8
Value of elm[j]106
Value of sourceArray index8
DEBUG
Value of i: 2
Value of j:1
Value of elm[j]9
Value of sourceArray index3
DEBUG
Value of i: 2
Value of j:2
Value of elm[j]26
Value of sourceArray index4
```

(Note not all accounts (for example i=1) have any `elm` assigned to it, and so can be ignored)

The sourceArray has been initialised with the correct size.

I have tried putting adding an additional value corresponding to the last index of the previous element but that resulted in exceeding the array size.

The file I am reading from, seen in the example:

```
0 22 36 39 45 56 81 89 106
1
2 9 26 51 58 75 86 89 101 102
...
```

Where the first elm is the account id and the rest are elms.

Comment: If you have array of primitive type the only way is to initialize the array with values that for sure won't be used in your core logic. So that each time you attempt to put a value to your array you would test if there is that initialized value exists. If not, then the cell considered occupied.

Comment: @AlexeyR. Oh the values are already initialized to all zeros. Just need to update to the correct values in the loop.

Comment: Having `0` is not actually a robust solution because if here `int src = Integer.parseInt(elm[j]);` you have `elm[j] == 0` then next time you would not distinguish if that is an `initial` value or that one that has to be protected from being overridden. If that's not the case just test `sourceArray[(i+j-1)] == 0` before putting value to the cell.. If `false` then skip the iteration.

Comment: But each  elm should go into the array. The array is of correct size to store all the elements. I believe the [(i+j-1)] needs some sort of constant/variable to prevent index overwrites, but I can't figure out how to implement that.

Comment: Ah.. I see.. So you read `elem` each time in outer (`i`) loop? If yes, does `elem` have each time the same length or it varies?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve with the assignment in question.  It looks like each row is a separate account.  It looks like you are trying to read all of the values into a single `int[]` with no way to identify where a given account starts/ends.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Solution: you have two-dimensional data, and inconsistent lengths. Don't try to do a fancy trick with storing indices under `(i * elm[i].length) + j -1` (typical mapping for a 2D array of constant sizes). Instead, keep an _actual_ 2D structure, like `int[][]` or `List<MyParsedAccount>`